# How to change the color of an image via CSS properties

Tags: css, vue.js, filter, figma, mix-blend-mode

https://www.figma.com/file/ZTyE9nUqVrZ9VFIXhZXL53/Superhuman-v1.0-(DEMO)?node-id=542%3A3625&mode=dev

The above link is a design draft, I want to make a Head male component, change the CSS by changing the skin prop. But I don't know how to do it. I tried using filter or mix-blend-mode properties, but it didn't solve the problem. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg as a component to render your image and pass the color as prop to it, something similar like this

```
<template>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" :fill="props.color" />
  </svg>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  color: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: 'yellow',
  },
});
</script>
```

And in your parent component

```
<template>
  <MyImage color="red"/>
</template>
```

Comment: But in the design draft, the Head male module is a `.png` image, which cannot be exported as `svg`

Comment: Maybe you can ask the designer to convert it to svg for you. Because I don't think we can change color of specific part of the image with css like a hair inside image. But with the fill property inside svg we can target to that specific area